# Insert data to array of array

Tags: javascript

i have this loop.
now, in a[i] im putting name of college, for example UCLA.
in temp i have the name of the player i want to insert into the `a[i][p]`

When im looking at `temp` im seeing the name that i actualy wants to insert, but them im
doing this line `a[i][p] = temp;`
im seeing in a[0][0]='U',
why?

[image]

```
var a = [[]];
var p = 0;
var temp;

for (var i = 0; i < uniq.length; i++) {
    a[i] = uniq[i];
    for (var k = 0; k < data.players.length; k++) {

        if (uniq[i] == data.players[k].college) 
        {
            temp = data.players[k].name
            a[i][p] = temp;
            p++;
        }
    }
    p = 0;

}
console.log(a[0][0])
```

Comment: With `a[0][0]` you are accessing the first element of the first element of a. 
a is in fact an array, so with `a[0]` you are accessing the first array value of a. In your case this is a string (not an array!). So with `a[0][0]` you get the first value of the string, which happens to be a 'U'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

1. first you put `UCLA` as the value of `a[0]`

now your array looks like this:

```
console.log(a[0]) // expected "UCLA"
```

2. `string`s in JavaScript can be iterated over - this means (roughly), that you can get `a[0][0]` in this case: the first item of the first item of the `a` array - and that is "the first character of the string at the first index in `a`"

```
console.log(a[0][0]) // expected: "U", if a[0] is "UCLA"
```

```js
const a = []
a[0] = "UCLA"

console.log(a)
console.log(a[0])
console.log(a[0][0])
```

You need to do it a bit differently (this could be one approach, but there could be more):

```js
const a = {} // this is an object, not an array!

a["UCLA"] = "name of tthe player"

console.log(a)
console.log(a["UCLA"])
```

Or, if you need an array, then you could do:

```js
const a = []

a[0] = { uni: "UCLA", player: [] }

a[0].player[0] = "name of the player"

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

when indexing JavaScript strings they behave like arrays and you actually get a 1 letter string with the character on the index you requested

for example:

```
var dummy = "house";
console.log(dummy[1]);
//this is going to return o (character in index 1 of house)
```

note that when indexing a string you are going to get another string and not a char like in other languages,

to achieve what you are trying to do you can use a dictionary like this:

```
var schools = {};
for (var i = 0; i < uniq.length; i++) {
    schools[uniq[i]] = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < data.players.length; k++) {

        if (uniq[i] == data.players[k].college) 
        {
            schools[uniq[i]].push(data.players[k].name);
        }
    }
}
```

at the end of this you can access schools either by indexing, by string key (college name) or with a simple foreach

```
schools[1]; //this is gonna give ["firstname","secondname","etc"] (player names of the second school)
schools["UCLA"]; //this is gonna give ["firstname","secondname","etc"] (player names of UCLA school)
```